# Bimorphism which is neither injective nor surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monomorphisms

In **Ring** the inclusion $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is a not surjective but injective bimorphism.

In **Div** the quotient map $g:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ is a not injective but surjective bimorphism.

So the question arises: Is there an algebraic category with a bimorphism which is neither injective nor surjective?

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraic category" ? For instance, $\mathbf{Div}$ is not concretely isomorphic to any category of algebras over a Lawvere theory (its forgetful functor has no left adjoint)

Comment: More generally, whenever there is a forgetful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$ that has a left adjoint (which one could take as a minimal requirement for being an "algebraic category"), it is representable so in particular it preserves monomorphisms, so for these any monomorphism will "be injective"

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just form the [product category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category) of the two examples you already gave?

I suggest this as a question, because I don't really know for certain that a pair of bimorphisms from the two categories is a bimorphism in the product category, but I suspect it is true. I also don't know if such a product is considered an "algebraic category."

Comment: Yes, OP will have to be more precise with what they mean by "algebraic category" (it's not even clear that $\mathbf{Div}$ is one). And to answer your first question, yes a couple of bimorphisms is a bimorphism (because a couple of monomorphisms is a pair of monomorphisms and a couple of epimorphisms is an epimorphism)

Comment: @Max Thank you. I looked up algebraic category in [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+category) but didn't have time to digest it. Some things that aren't obviously algebraic turn out to be algebraic, so perhaps it is true. The question whether that definition was meant here also remains :(

Comment: given this definition at the nlab, neither $\mathbf{Div}$ nor your category are algebraic (included in the definition is that every set has a free object, so in particular $U$ should have a left adjoint, but that is not the case for $\mathbf{Div}$). In fact, as I explained in a comment under the post, any algebraic category (according to the nlab definition) has its monomorphisms injective.  But I agree that it's not clear that this is what OP meant

Comment: @Max Why aren't the free objects just pairs of free objects?

Comment: $\mathbf{Div}$ doesn't have any free objects (if it had, $U$ would preserve limits, but for instance the equalizer of $\mathbb{ Q\rightrightarrows Q/Z}$ (projection and $0$ map) is $0$ in $\mathbf{Div}$, and $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbf{Set}$)

Comment: @Max OH, hah, yeah. I did not even pay attention to **Div**.  But in general if the two pieces have free objects, the product will use pairs of those as free objects?

Comment: @Max I did not even realize categories could be completely devoid of free objects... thank you for explaining that.

Comment: You have to be more precise about the formulation, but yes if you have $U,V$ as forgetful functors and take $(A,B)\mapsto U(A)\times V(B)$ as a forgetful functor on the product category, then $(F(X),G(X))$ will be free on $X$, where $F(X)$ is free on $X$ and $G(X)$ similarly (in the appropriate categories).

Comment: And yes, some categories don't even have an available notion of free object, that is, they don't have a forgetful functor (with some reasonable interpretation of "forgetful"), but here $\mathbf{Div}$ has such a notion but no free objects